# c3p0 useScatteredAquireTask Spring Bean

Tags: spring, c3p0

Hello I wan't to know how can I set up a bean so that it sets the ScatteredAquireTask to "True".

I've been trying:

```
<bean id="c3p0Props" class="com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.ScatteredAcquireTask" >
<property name="USE_SCATTTERED_ACQUIRE_TASK" value="true" />
</bean>
```

I also tried ...resourcepool.experimental.useScatteredAcquireTask... didn't worked. I'm not sure how can I set this on spring. I'm using 0.9.1.2, can't go to 0.9.2.prep1 at the moment. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because `USE_SCATTTERED_ACQUIRE_TASK` isn't a property of the `ScatteredAcquireTask` class (i.e. there's no method called `setUSE_SCATTTERED_ACQUIRE_TASK`), it's an internal static field of the class that's not accessible to Spring.

You're not going to be able to set that values in a Spring bean defintion, you need to find out how to influence that value by some other means.